# Node Wrangler Cycle Through Inputs

Tags: texturing, node-editor, workflow

When I want to "lazy connect" (ctrl + shift + Left Click) a node with a certain input of another node, the Node Wrangler often connects to the wrong input. What is the shortcut to switch the input or cycle through different inputs (and outputs)? I tried alt + s, but that's not the right one because it just swaps two existing connections. I really want the shortcut to give me all options, so I can keep hitting it until I have got the right one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm more than a little confused by this question CTRL-SHIFT-LMB is the shortcut for connecting the selected node to the viewer.  ALT-RMB is the shortcut for lazy connect. If you want to pick the destination node use SHIFT-ALT-RMB. It'll pop up a menu of nodes to chose from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node Wrangler](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) has different keymaps and shortcuts depending on the version of Blender you are using it with.  In recent versions of Blender <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–LMB is not the shortcut for *lazy connect*.

You can verify this by editing *Preferences*, going to the *Add-ons* tab, and finding *Node Wrangler*. If you search the keymap for lazy you get

[image: Node Wrangle add-on preferences showing the shortcuts for lazy]

If the shortcut for lazy functions in your version of blender is not as shown, you need to do a similar search in your preferences.  This answer assumes a recent version of blender.

The other thing that is different in recent versions of Blender is that cycling through the input sockets by clicking has been replaced by *Lazy Connect with Socket Menu*.  If you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–RMB drag, when you release the mouse, a menu pops up allowing you to select the destination socket:

[image: Menu for selecting sockets]

In this case, since I'm connecting to a Principled node and it has many color inputs, if I pick color, a second popup appears:

[image: Submenu for selecting specific color]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> normally connects your clicked node with the viewer node. Don't lift your fingers, just click again on that node, then it will cycle through the inputs.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + LMB connects the selected socket to the viewer node.